# How to remove a trailing question mark (empty query string) from the URL?

Tags: nginx

Given an url such as `example.com/page?` I would like to strip the trailing question mark from the URL to avoid Google treating `example.com/page?` as a duplicate of `example.com/page`.

Ideally, `example.com/page?` should return a 301 redirect to `example.com/page`. How can I accomplish this with Nginx?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question mark is not part of path, so url with and without `?` point to same location. You no need to fix for Google or in Nginx.

Just to have more pretty URL's fix code, which generate ugly URLs.